# How to assign a sum of values within fields to a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, aggregate-functions, variable-assignment

I have an SQL statement which selects various data from a table in my database and I have declared variables within my code like:

```
DECLARE @TotalAge int;
```

Let's say one of the fields in the table is `Age`, how would I sum the collected values from the query and assign them to the variable as a total?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First set `@TotalAge`:

```
set @TotalAge=(select sum(Age) from TableName)
```

then select `@TotalAge` where you want:

```
select @TotalAge
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use :

```
      SET @TotalAge = (SELECT SUM(Age) FROM YourTable)
```

or

```
      SELECT @TotalAge  = SUM(Age) FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

use `SET` to assign some:

```
SET @TotalAge = (SELECT SUM(Age) FROM YourTable)
```